# What to pass into LinearLayout constructor

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, android-linearlayout

Hi guys :) I am storing products for my android app in a Parse database and trying to load them up at run-time.

I  want to create a `LinearLayout` in the 'done' method below but I am not sure how to pass the `Context` in the `LinearLayout` constructor.  What do I put in the contructor's parameter?

Thank you!

```
public class BrowseActivity extends Activity {

    //do stuff here

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /*Get all services and packages from parse database*/
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("InAppProducts");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e)
            {

                if(e == null)
                {
                    /*Add products to page*/
                     //What do I put where "this" is?
                     LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);



                }
                else{

                }


            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: read the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `BrowseActivity.this` or `getBaseContext()` here. But please don't use `getApplicationContext()` as other answers suggests. View's should be created with Activity context, then only it will get destroyed and garbage collected along with Activity.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `getApplicationContext()` or `BrowseActivity.this`

Comment: -1, You should always try to not use getApplicationContext() when creating view hierarchies. That will result the view to stay in memory even after your activity get destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Krishnabhadra is correct, passing an application context won't let the view garbage collected even if the activity gets destroyed. So use instead BrowseActivity.this or getBaseContext() to get Activity context.